# Recyclerview java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am doing a chat bot using arraylist and Watson Conversation API to fetch the bot response after a user input a message. Users will input some messages and the bot API will show a response based on the user input. There are no errors when a user inputs something that has been set up in the Watson API. However when a user types a message that the bot does not understand, this error will show up.

I am not sure how to restructure the codes to solve this issue. I hope someone could help and tell me what to do. Thank you in advanced! :(

```
public class BotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BotActivity";
    private String userText;

    private EditText userInput;
    private LinearLayout welcomeText;

    private ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bot);

        userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        welcomeText = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.centerLayout);

        addItems();
    }

    private void addItems() {

        userInput.setImeOptions(userInput.getImeOptions() | EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        userInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                    welcomeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    titleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    userText = userInput.getText().toString().trim();
                    nameList.add(userText);
                    imageList.add("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/7c/90/997c901be018004a07d66ae4920fd3a6.png");
                    userInput.setText("");

                    setRecyclerView();

                    final ConversationService myConversationService = new ConversationService(
                            "2017-05-26",
                            getString(R.string.username),
                            getString(R.string.password)
                    );

                    MessageRequest request = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(userText).build();

                    myConversationService.message(getString(R.string.workspace), request)
                            .enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {

                                    final String outputText = response.getText().get(0);

                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            nameList.add(outputText);
                                            imageList.add("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fGmmzMLA4zw/VLSHyleQbXI/AAAAAAAAODw/YevIrHiSJ7o/s1600/blushicon.png");
                                            setRecyclerView();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    if (response.getIntents().get(0).getIntent().endsWith("RequestQuote")) {

                                        String quotesURL = "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/" + "?method=getQuote&format=text&lang=en";

                                        Fuel.INSTANCE.get(quotesURL, null).responseString(new Handler<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void success(String quote) {

                                                nameList.add(quote);
                                                imageList.add("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fGmmzMLA4zw/VLSHyleQbXI/AAAAAAAAODw/YevIrHiSJ7o/s1600/blushicon.png");
                                                setRecyclerView();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void failure(@NotNull FuelError fuelError) {
                                                Toast.makeText(BotActivity.this, fuelError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                                }
                            });
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        BotAdapter adapter = new BotAdapter(this, nameList, imageList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

and this is the coding of the bot adapter:

```
public class BotAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BotAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "BotAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> profileImageList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private JumpingBeans jumpingBeans;

    public BotAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> nameList, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
        this.messageList = nameList;
        this.profileImageList = imageList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_bot_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(profileImageList.get(i))
                .into(viewHolder.showProfileImage);

        viewHolder.showMessage.setText(messageList.get(i));
        viewHolder.showMessage.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // click on recycler items action
                // Toast.makeText(context, messageList.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView showMessage;
        private CircleImageView showProfileImage;
        private RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            showMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showMessage);
            showProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showImage);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_single_layout);

        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
05-05 11:47:24.826 9840-9994/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OkHttp: --> POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/7e18adc0-c6db-4897-a83c-17c788db377e/message?version=2017-05-26 http/1.1 (27-byte body)
05-05 11:47:25.076 9840-9994/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/7e18adc0-c6db-4897-a83c-17c788db377e/message?version=2017-05-26 (245ms, unknown-length body)
05-05 11:47:25.076 9840-9994/com.amethyst.secretgarden E/BotActivity: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-05 11:47:25.656 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OppoEditor: OppoEditor, classname = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView,packageName = com.amethyst.secretgarden
05-05 11:47:25.716 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OppoEditor: OppoEditor, classname = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView,packageName = com.amethyst.secretgarden
05-05 11:47:25.736 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OppoEditor: OppoEditor, classname = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView,packageName = com.amethyst.secretgarden
05-05 11:47:25.736 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OppoEditor: OppoEditor, classname = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView,packageName = com.amethyst.secretgarden
05-05 11:47:25.736 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/OppoEditor: OppoEditor, classname = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView,packageName = com.amethyst.secretgarden
05-05 11:47:30.526 9840-9855/com.amethyst.secretgarden I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 92796(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 18MB/24MB, paused 1.611ms total 273.636ms
05-05 11:47:38.986 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 85341
05-05 11:47:38.996 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden V/FA: Connecting to remote service
05-05 11:47:39.076 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden V/FA: Activity paused, time: 14744243
05-05 11:47:39.116 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=85341, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=BotActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=6871416413478563474}]
05-05 11:47:39.276 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-05 11:47:39.276 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden D/FA: Connected to remote service
05-05 11:47:39.276 9840-10155/com.amethyst.secretgarden V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
05-05 11:47:39.286 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden W/InputMethodManager: startInputInner : InputBindResult == null need restart
05-05 11:47:39.306 9840-9840/com.amethyst.secretgarden W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: post your error stack trace

Comment: added the error

Comment: error may be in this line "response.getIntents().get(0)" where there will be no list and you are trying to get 0th index. so first try to check null and lenght or size > 0 for that

Comment: You should not call `setRecyclerView()` on every response. It is very inefficient. You should use `AsyncListDiffer`

Comment: Check if `messageList` empty or not before binding

Comment: From your log, I can see that the errors come from Activity class

Comment: @SouravBagchi can you show me where/how to do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149